# javascript variable with a-tag (string build)

Tags: javascript, string, url, concatenation

I am having trouble with this markup i programmatically insert into an editor. I don't know how to add the target="_blank" attribute. I can't get it to work even tho i tried '" "' or "' "' and all sort of combinations. I don't know what this task i called either so i can't really google it. 
Any help would be appreciated to make this work

```
var html = "<a href='" + host + "/draught/connect/Download" + draughtDownloadType + "?PropId=" + selectedPropertyId + autoUpdateQuery + "' target=_blank>" + linkText + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` character by placing a `\` infront of it.

```
target=\"_blank\"
```

To give you:

```
var html = "<a href='" + host + "/draught/connect/Download" + draughtDownloadType + "?PropId=" + selectedPropertyId + autoUpdateQuery + "' target=\"_blank\">" + linkText + "</a>";
```

Comment: thank you! This worked perfectly. That is exactly what i wanted to do. But i didn't know it was called escape so i couldn't google it :)

Comment: No worries @Phil_TheAverage - searching for syntax is always hard!

Answer (score 0):

use escape

```
var html = "<a href='" + host + "/draught/connect/Download" + draughtDownloadType + "?PropId=" + selectedPropertyId + autoUpdateQuery + "' target=\"_blank\">" + linkText + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **target='_blank'**. In JS while doing concatenation then you can use **'** inside "" without any issue and vice-versa.